# Unknown bucket while doing gcsfuse

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcsfuse

I want to fuse a gcs bucket with a local directory, for which I'm doing the following:

gcsfuse gs://stereo-train ~/Documents/stereo-train

However, I'm getting the error:

```
Unknown bucket "gs://stereo-train"
```

The stereo train bucket does exist on google cloud. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by the [docs](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/mounting.md#mounting), when you want to mount the bucket using `gcsfuse` you only type the name of the bucket without adding "`gs://`", i.e., you may want to mount the bucket using:

`gcsfuse stereo-train ~/Documents/stereo-train`